# Why aren't these magic methods recursive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, operator-overloading

Here's a Python class that implements some [magic methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html):

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def inc(self):
        self.value += 1
        return self.value

    def dec(self):
        self.value -= 1
        return self.value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.value > other

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value < other

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        try:
            self.value
        except:
            pass
        else:
            print(name, "changed its value from", self.value, "to", value)
        finally:
            super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

It implements (albeit redundant) methods defined on some objects, and allows comparison and (in the `__setattr__` case) assignment hooking:

```
>>> a.inc()
value changed its value from 0 to 1
1
```

Suppose we redefine `__setattr__` to make it simpler:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    self.__setattr__(name, value)
```

Now trying to assign to `self.value` will get you a slap in the face:

```
  File "<pyshell#50>", line 17, in __setattr__
    self.__setattr__(name, value)
  File "<pyshell#50>", line 17, in __setattr__
    self.__setattr__(name, value)
  File "<pyshell#50>", line 17, in __setattr__
    self.__setattr__(name, value)
  File "<pyshell#50>", line 17, in __setattr__
    self.__setattr__(name, value)
  File "<pyshell#50>", line 17, in __setattr__
    self.__setattr__(name, value)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Well, that was expected. The function `__setattr__` is recursive; that's why we need to use `super()`.

My question is, why doesn't this recursivity apply for the other magic methods; that is, when I call `obj.__gt__(otherval)`, it is the same as saying `obj > otherval`, which is a call to `obj.__gt__(otherval)`, which is a call to... well, you get it.

It does not result in the `>` used in the method calling its own method. Why?

Comment: What do you expect `self.value` to do in `__setattr__`? You never delete that attribute anywhere, so the `try..except..else` always goes to `else`.

Comment: that's not the point. he is simply demonstrating that __setattr__() **is** recursive, but __gt__() is not.

Comment: @MartijnPieters when initialising an instance of `A`, you'll get `name self.value` is not defined because the value cannot be set without first existing. Remove the try block, try to print the assigned value and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: `__setattr__` is hitting an endless loop, yes, because you *explicitly call it*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, with `a.inc()` or similar.

Comment: @rbp: I used a comment to ask clarification about a puzzling bit of code. The `try..except` there makes no sense, as it is entirely redundant.

Comment: Not related to this question, but avoid using bare `except:` blocks

Comment: @MartijnPieters it's not redundant at all, else I wouldn't have put it there: only after trying it without the try block, initialising it `a = A(0)` will get you 
`AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'value'` because the attribute has to first exist before it can be assigned to.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I'm aware, however, it's for the purpose of demonstration and simplicity and the only reasonable thing for `self.value` to raise in this snippet is `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not invoking `>` on `self`. You are invoking it on `self.value`, which is an integer value (e.g. a completely different type).

If you used:

```
def __gt__(self, other):
    return self > other
```

you'd end up in an endless loop too.